# How to save pivot table as permanent table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a pivot table in MS Sql Server 2008.  How can I save the resulting pivot table to a permanent table?

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT yr as [year], lname as [player], avg_rating as Rating
  FROM pool_ratings_yr1) as s
PIVOT
  (SUM(Rating) FOR [player] in (greenleaf, maturo, allen, caras, concannon, taberski, mosconi, weston, seaback, deoro, blankenship, ralph, keough, kreuter, layton, hueston, rudolph, lauri) ) AS pool_pivot
```

Thanks,
Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`SELECT INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029%28SQL.100%29.aspx):

```
SELECT *
INTO dbo.Permanent_Table_1
FROM 
(
  SELECT yr as [year], lname as [player], avg_rating as Rating
  FROM dbo.pool_ratings_yr1
) as s
PIVOT
(
   SUM(Rating) FOR [player] in (greenleaf, maturo, allen, caras, 
      concannon, taberski, mosconi, weston, seaback, deoro, blankenship, 
      ralph, keough, kreuter, layton, hueston, rudolph, lauri) 
) AS pool_pivot;
```